# How can I set up domain-name-access to home server using cloud server with public IP and VPN?

Tags: ssh, dns, proxy, nat, ssh-tunnel

```
                 srv_pub                               srv_target 
           +-----------------+                  +---------------------+
  Internet |      VPS        |  VPN 10.8.0.0/24 |     HOME SERVER     |
-----------> eth0: public_ip <------------------> eth0: non_public_ip |
           | tun0:  10.8.0.1 |                  | tun0: 10.8.0.2      |
           +-----------------+                  +---------------------+
Domains:     pub.example.com                   srv.example.com (desired)
```

Current situation: target server (`srv_target`) has no public IP and connected to other server with public IP (`srv_pub`) using OpenVPN. I need to setup access to srv_target using domain name.

In particular It means that:

- if i type `ssh user@srv.example.com` on some other host somewhere at Internet - i will go to `srv_target`
- `curl http://srv.example.com` will be addressed to port 80 of `srv_target`
- `ping srv.example.com` outside will ping `srv_target`
- `srv_pub` stay accessible by http, ssh and icmp via domain and public IP.

How to do that ?

Do I need to setup DNS server on `srv_pub` with `A` record that points `srv.example.com` to `10.8.0.2`?

Do I need to create additional tunnels using software like [sshuttle](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle) ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 2 things -

1. Set DNS to point to the public IP address of your srv-public (there is no point in setting ot up to a private IP - it cant get there!)
2. Set up NAT and port forwarding on srv-public to go forward traffic on to srv-target.  You have not advised yourcos/distro, but on Linux this can be done using

#Turn on IP forwarding
echo 1 />proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

## redirect traffic from ext IP to internal IP.

iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d pub.ip.add.res --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.1

Notes:

1. The above command needs ti be repeated for all relevant ports.
2. You need to ensure the default route traffic fron the private IP is going out the VPN and being madqueraded. (ie dont try the above until the vpn is set up and pushing a default route and working)
3. Take into account the difficulties managing the pyblic server if ssh is redirected to the vpn.  You probably want to set ssh up on an alternative port (unless you are confident wuth the vpn or have a remote console).

If this is only for ssh and http(s) there us another pissibility - set up a reverse proxy for http(s) - this can be done with Apache using ProxyPass directives or similarly with nginx - without resorting to iptables rules and rouring all traffic via the vpn - and will allow you to set up web server at home and on the vpn.

Similarly you can configure SSH so that it acts as a jumpbox/bastion - there are multiple ways to do this depebding on exactly what you are trying, but the ProxyCommand or ProxyJump directive can be useful.

Comment: ... and set up routing on target server to reply via VPN to packets that arrived from VPN

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter *where* you set up the DNS server (or use existing one). DNS doesn't relay data, all it provides is the address, but the actual connection is made using the client's own capabilities.

So if you create an `A` record pointing to your network's internal IP address, it will only be accessible to clients already connected to the network (e.g. devices that are VPN'd in). Outside clients will be able to resolve the address but not reach it.

That means the DNS records must point to a **public** address – if your VPS only has one public IPv4 address, then that's what must go in your DNS records, and your home server will need to "share" the same address somehow.

Usually this means keeping the address on the VPS, but using iptables or nftables `DNAT` rules to "port forward" specific ports to your home server. (This is literally the same port-forwarding as you have at home.)

Because you only have one address, things like SSH will need to go on nonstandard ports – e.g. port 22 remains for SSH to the VPS itself, while port 5022 is forwarded to your home server, and there's nothing you can do about ping here, it'll always go to one machine.

(Also keep in mind that the home server needs to *respond* through tun0, not through eth0, so you'll likely need "policy routing" for that. Search the site for `ip rule`, it's been described several times.)

Only HTTP and HTTPS are in a better situation – all HTTP requests indicate the domain name, so in case both machines need to serve HTTP at the same time, you can use a *reverse proxy* to have the VPS internally route all requests for `http://srv.example.com` to `http://10.8.0.2`, without the troubles of DNAT port-forwarding.

The situation would be improved if the VPS had *two* IP addresses – then one could remain assigned to the VPS itself, while the other routed through the VPN and assigned to your server (...or everything DNATed to the server). With IPv6 that's easy, but if you need to accept IPv4 clients then getting a 2nd IP address from the VPS provider will cost extra.

Additional tunnels like sshuttle won't help in this situation. They don't really do anything that couldn't be done with the existing VPN tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

While all you you asking about is possible to do exactly, it is not very good solution. Especially bad is an idea to forward ping. There is other way, usually it is preferred. Either way, you don't need any additional tunnels.

Let the virtual NIC that has 10.8.0.x addresses to be named `tun0` on both servers. By the way, it depends on the OpenVPN mode, in more widely used client-server setup your server will have an address `10.8.0.6` instead. I strongly suggest to use `tun` mode for this VPN, because it is more efficient. (You use `tap` mode only when you exactly know you need that.)

Let's also assume for the sake of explanation that public IP address of *srv_pub* is `192.0.2.1`,  You'll need to set up public DNS for both names:

```
pub.example.com. A 192.0.2.1
srv.example.com. CNAME pub.example.com.
```

I suggest CNAME to only change one record should your public IP change.

The rest depends on the configuration way you choose. (There may be other ways, these two just come to my mind.)

### Better way

Better way is more controllable, also it is easier to configure and support.

- Set up **reverse HTTP(s) proxy** on the *srv_pub*. You can use Apache, Nginx, Caddy for that; there are plenty of manuals how to do that, including those on ServerFault. You'll create the `srv.example.com` virtual host and proxy it to `10.8.0.2`.
- Notice that **this server will terminate HTTP(s)**, you install your public HTTP(s) certificates there; in case of Let's Encrypt, you also install ACME client on *srv_pub* and it will control both domain names.
- On `srv.example.com` better reconfigure the logging to save real client's IP addresses instead of proxy address `10.8.0.1`.
- Make sure `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on *srv_pub* has `AllowTcpForwarding` enabled
- Create a user name for SSH to connect to this *srv_pub*. It is only needed to forward SSH connection through. I'll refer to it as to `forward_user`. A target user which you will use on *srv_target* let's call `target_user`.
- I don't know which software you are going to use to connect via SSH. However, I recommend to use OpenSSH, which is installed in Linux as well as available as a feature in recent Windows. You can configure it to connect to srv_target through srv_pub. For that, add the following into `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host pub.example.com
    User forward_user
    
Host srv.example.com
    User target_user
    ProxyJump pub.example.com
    HostName 10.8.0.2
```

- You'll need to configure this on each system which is going to connect to those servers. Also I strongly recommend to create SSH key pair, again, each system should have its own pair. Generate a pair on your local computer, and distrubute the private key to both servers, easiest way to do it is to run `ssh-copy-id pub.example.com` and `ssh-copy-id srv.example.com`. There are plenty of instructions about SSH keys out here and there.

Now, http will reach the `srv.example.com` through the proxy on `pub.example.com`.

The command `ssh srv.example.com` will connect to `pub.example.com`, setup port forwarding to `srv.example.com` and connect to it through this forwarding. It will do this behind the scenes, and everything will appear as if you just connected to target server, as expected by running this command. If you set up keys, it'll won't ask for passwords; you can use SSH agent to enter key passphrase only once after login to the local system.

And about ping. It is pointless. If you want to monitor `srv.example.com`, configure e.g. Zabbix agent on target host and proxy on `pub.example.com` or some other way.

### Exact way

Although I think this is not the best way to achieve your goal, I'll describe it, because it is built exactly in a way you asked it.

- On your VPN host, you first need to move SSH to other port. This is to be able to connect there after you installed forwarding rule. Set up `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to say `Port 2222` or something like this and restart the service.
- Then you forward ports. Don't forget to enable IP forwarding:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -m multiport --dport 22,80,443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2
echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.d/forwarding.conf
```

- And now you need to set up target server to either route all server traffic through VPN, or set up policy routing so replies to packets that come from VPN will be replied through VPN.

Notice this ping forward is like shooting yourself into foot. It will be misleading. Better skip it. Never forward pings. Or prepare to have fun when something breaks and you'll need debugging.